# google map's street view data parameter

Tags: jquery, google-maps

i am embedding different rooms ex(Room 1 and Room 2) of a location into a site but changing the latitude and longitude of the rooms in the code is resulting in no change . If I open the url of Room1 and then copy the latitude and longitude of room2 in that url that is also not working until I change data parameter of the url (data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1so_4Sy2LwH_cAAAQfCSpdzg). The code which i am using is

```
function initializeaboutus() { 
 var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(41.89877,-87.622917);
 var panoramaOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
     heading: 2,
     pitch: 0
   }
 };
 var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('aboutusinsidemap'),panoramaOptions);
// map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeaboutus);
```

Is there any method to change the data parameter in this code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you want to have `new google.maps.LatLng(41.89877,-87.622917);` dynamic?

Comment: no i have values of latitude and longitude but it is not loading the exact location of the rooms

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the value of `heading` and `pitch`, so that you can change the view of the camera.

for example:

with heading 40 degree:
http://jsfiddle.net/spatjqo4/

with heading 20 degree:
http://jsfiddle.net/spatjqo4/1/